# How to change privacy indicator shape in LineageOS code?

Tags: android-source

I am currently building a Custom ROM, and i want to change the privacy indicator shape which is currently a rectangle with rounded corners and is that green thing on the status bar if an app uses the camera/mic/location into an circle (just like in OneUI). Since i am new in coding in AOSP/LineageOS, i have a few questions:

1. In which directory and the code file determines the shape of the privacy indicator?
2. Do i need to change the location of the icon too to make it fit inside the new privacy indicator?
3. How can i change in the code how long the privacy indicator appears before it turns into an green dot?

Thanks in advance.

I cant find the code since im new in coding with AOSP and LineageOS